# print rows by matching order from other file

Tags: linux, awk, bioinformatics

file1.txt

```
SRR1071717
SRR1079830
SRR1081765
SRR1085402
SRR1086236
SRR1092208
SRR1093930
SRR1097296
SRR1099957
SRR1120296
```

file2.txt

```
SRR1120296,female
SRR1099957,male
SRR1097296,female
SRR1093930,female
SRR1092208,female
SRR1086236,female
SRR1085402,male
SRR1081765,male
SRR1079830,male
SRR1071717,male
```

Desired output

```
SRR1071717  male
SRR1079830  male
SRR1081765  male
SRR1085402  male
SRR1086236  female
SRR1092208  female
SRR1093930  female
SRR1097296  female
SRR1099957  male
SRR1120296  female
```

I want to maintain the order of file1.txt to print file2.txt. Both files have equal rows (can't use sort because order will be changed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try

```
awk -v FS="," 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next}; {if ($1 in a) print $1,a[$1]}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

FNR==NR means first file

a[$1]=$2 is like a[SRR1120296]=female

second file if SRR1120296 is index in array a then print SRR1120296 and array value

Comment: No need for `if` - `'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a{print $1,a[$1]}'`

Answer (score -1):

You could store the lines from `file2.txt` into an array, the print them by using indices from `file1.txt`. `NR==FNR` is the condition that you are reading the first file (which is `file2.txt`, note the order of the arguments).

```bash
awk -F, '{if (NR==FNR) a[$1]=$0; else print a[$1]}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

```
SRR1071717,male
SRR1079830,male
SRR1081765,male
SRR1085402,male
SRR1086236,female
SRR1092208,female
SRR1093930,female
SRR1097296,female
SRR1099957,male
SRR1120296,female
```